# Weka Random Forest Property defination

Tags: random-forest, weka, training-data, feature-selection, batchsize

I am using Weka for classifying a binary dataset. I would like to use `RandomForest` as a classifier. I found `RandomForest` has number of properties. I would like to know the meaning of those properties and how they work in the time of classification. Weka shares some details which can be found from the more tab of the property window of `RandomForest`.

I am attaching the screenshot herewith

[image]

There are some definition of those properties:

bagSizePercent -- Size of each bag, as a percentage of the training set size.

numIterations -- The number of trees in the random forest.

outputOutOfBagComplexityStatistics -- Whether to output complexity-based statistics when out-of-bag evaluation is performed

numFeatures -- Sets the number of randomly chosen attributes. If 0, int(log_2(#predictors) + 1) is used.

and so on.

So those 1 lines unable to clear my doubt. If someone help me by sharing the in depth view of the properties that would be very helpful.

Comment: In this [link](https://weka.sourceforge.io/doc.dev/weka/classifiers/trees/RandomForest.html) you can see all features defined. Anyway, the features that you show are quite habitual when talking about Random Forest. You should understand almost all of them. For example, numIterations and numFeatures are basic features that the RandomForest uses. If you don't know what they mean, you should first understand deeper the algorithm. I would recommend some video in youtube like Random Forest Statquest.

Comment: Which one among this features need to adjust if my dataset is unbalanced? Thank You.